# Infinite loop that does not crash but causes 300% CPU

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this code that makes my app hang and Expo using 300% CPU. It looks like an infinite loop but it does not crash and I can't figure out why it's an infinite loop or why its not crashing.

I scraped out the useless parts:

ContainerComponent.js

```
const [cardsReady, setCardsReady] = useState(0)

const cardLoaded = () => {
    setCardsReady(cardsReady + 1)
}

return keys.map((component) => {
<Card key={'some key} 
    articles={'somearticle'} color={'#eeeeee'} 
    onLoaded={cardLoaded}
    category={'some category}
/>
})
```

Card.js

```
useEffect(() => {
onLoaded()

})
```

Comment: How are you testing and debugging this code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905322/how-do-you-stop-an-infinite-loop-in-javascript Look for a "slow script performance" warning and try to kill it.  Then, read Drew's comment.

Comment: `onLoaded` updates the state in the parent component which will rerender the parent which will rerender `Card`, this will cause a render loop since there is no dependency on the `useEffect` hook; it will call its callback every render. Sounds like it should load only once, use an empty dependency (`[]`) array to run the effect only once when the component mounts.

Answer (score 0):

please use a dependencies array to only execute useEffect hook once.

Card.js

```
useEffect(() => {
onLoaded()

},[]);
```

In the dependencies array you can leave it empty for execute it once as i said or put dependencies variables, that is, specify the variables when it value changes will execute code inside `useEffect`.

Comment: I tried both, I put a console log inside cardLoaded and it's not even firing, just really high CPU

Comment: And? The loop stills there?

Comment: Nothing happens as soon as I trigger the .map to render the Card components it stops doing anything and eats CPU

Comment: How many Cards are you rendering? May you can use react-virtualized

Comment: 19, I will take a look at react-virtualized

Comment: It's a dynamic number, I am just trying to keep track of when ALL my Cards components are done rendering by increment to a known number so I can show a loading in the meantime, my logic may be bad, any other suggestions to keep track of this kind of thing?

Before this attempt I did not had any issue rendering

Comment: Its very weird anyway...its only 19 cards...unless it spends a lot of resources. Virtualized is for rendering manipulation, it prevents all component renders at the same time, but i dont know if it will fit to your needs

Answer (score 0):

The issue here with your code is with every state update in functional component it is re-rendered.
To avoid that issue you need to add dependency array to useEffect, and we are checking the if the component has mounted or not

Card.js

```
const Card = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if(mounted && props.onLoaded){
      props.onLoaded();
    }
    return () => mounted=false;
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  },[]);
  return <div></div>;
};
```

I have created a local state to check whether the component is loaded or not. I know the answer is a bit complicated